# Module '@hookform/resolvers' has no exported member 'yupResolver'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have the following import in my component, but it's causing an error.

`import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers";`

```
ERROR in ./src/components/pages/Forms.tsx 26:14-25
export 'yupResolver' (imported as 'yupResolver') was not found in '@hookform/resolvers' (possible exports: toNestError, validateFieldsNatively)
>
>webpack compiled with 1 error and 1 warning
ERROR in src/components/pages/Forms.tsx:2:10
TS2305: Module '"@hookform/resolvers"' has no exported member 'yupResolver'.

    1 | import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
  > 2 | import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers";
      |          ^^^^^^^^^^^
    3 | import * as yup from "yup";
```

Comment: Can you add your `package.json` file to the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are not setting the poth correctly to  **[yupResolver](https://github.com/react-hook-form/resolvers/blob/master/yup/src/yup.ts)**

**change :**

```
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers";
```

**to  :**

```
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
```

Comment: i tested it but not work!

Comment: did you install `@hookform/resolvers` ?

Comment: yeah i installed it

Answer (score 0):

npm install @hookform/resolvers need to install it first

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).